# JSP Compilation Exception

Tags: java, maven, jboss, slf4j, jasper-plugin

We have updated our **JBoss** from **4.3** to **7.3** and **Java** from **1.6** to **1.8**. And there is one module in particular in our project that does not compile. Can someone please point me where to look for fixing this?

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
     at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.cTrace
     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
            at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1040)
            at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1156)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.jspc.compiler.tomcat6.JreateCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:229)
            at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:996)
            at org.apache.jasper.JspCspCompilerImpl.compile(JspCompilerImpl.java:111)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Delega.execute(JspC.java:1156)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.jspc.compiler.tomcat6.JspCompilerImpl.compile(JspCompilerImpl.java:111)
            at suntingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.Cached.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
            at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Mepl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:756)
            at org.codehaus.grthod.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
            at groovy.lang.Metaoovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:766)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(Method.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
            at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
            at groovy.lang.InvokerHelper.java:754)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
            aMetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:756)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelpert org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethod0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:198)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.jspc.Co.java:766)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:754)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.mpilationMojoSupport.execute(CompilationMojoSupport.groovy:333)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DeScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokfaultPluginManager.java:490)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.javaeMethod0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:198)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.jspc.CompilationMojoSupport.execute(CompilationMojoSupport.groov:694)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
            at y:333)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecyorg.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecyccle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExele.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Defacutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execuultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecteGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(utor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
            at org.apaDefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleche.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
            at org.apacheExecutor.java:348)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
            at org..maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
            a       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.t org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.javainvoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.classworlds:60)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.la.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
            at org.codehaus.cng.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
            at org.codelassworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
            Caused bhaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
            at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
            y: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
            at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCo at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
            mpilationContext.java:229)
            at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:996)
            ... 34 more
```

I can't figure out whether there's something wrong with the **jasper** module or if iti simply can't find **SLF4J** (We did remove **SLF4J** from the project). Maybe the jasper module calls **SLF4J** code and its not there anymore?

And why does it say No **Java** compiler available?

Comment: Looks like you run on a JRE not on a JDK. Please try `java --version` which java is running

Comment: its java 1.8.0.

Comment: JRE or JDK?   ...

Comment: Both the JRE and JDK are 1.8